# Where is the data string located in this disassembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

I am going through the [OS-dev](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk//%7Eexr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf) book by Nick Blundell and I am disassembling the code in section 5.1.4.

Specifically, I have this c code stored in `string.c`:

```
void my_function()
{
    char* str = "Hello";
}
```

I compile it in 32-bit mode (since I am on 64-bit linux) this way:

`gcc -ffreestanding -fno-pie -m32 -c string.c -o string.o`

Linking step:

`ld -m elf_i386 -o string.bin -Ttext 0x0 --oformat binary string.o`

And disassembly:

`ndisasm -b 32 string.bin > string.dis`

And here is my result:

```
00000000  55                push ebp
00000001  89E5              mov ebp,esp
00000003  83EC10            sub esp,byte +0x10
00000006  C745FC00100000    mov dword [ebp-0x4],0x1000
0000000D  90                nop
0000000E  C9                leave
0000000F  C3                ret
```

I see that the compiler is allocating 16-bytes on the third line but I don't see where the "hello" string is located. I especially don't understand what happens at the 4th line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

0x1000

Don't look for strings in the code segment. That's not where they are. The only instruction that is not part of the prologue or epilogue is `mov dword [ebp-0x4],0x1000`; which is clearly setting the local variable `str` to `0x1000`. And we know that `str` points to the string.

Strings aren't in the text segment. They're in the rodata segment. Did you omit the rodata segment on linking?

(You compiled at -O0. Thus the dead code variable assignment was not removed.)

Comment: `.text` and `.rodata` are sections; that's what `objdump` looks for when deciding where to start/stop disassembling.  But yes, `.rodata` does get linked into a separate segment (with read but not exec permission, unlike `.text`).

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'm confused. How does `objdump` know where the boundaries are when disassembling a `bin` format file?

Comment: Oh, it doesn't, and this is `ndisasm` not `objdump`, oops.  But for some reason the OP omitted the rest of the file. (The 128 MiB of zeros before the `.rodata` section at its normal address 08048000 in a 32-bit non-PIE, since they only overrode the start address for `text` not `rodata`)  So that's weird, it's storing the wrong address for the string literal, it should be `mov dword [ebp-0x4], 0x08048000`.  The linker should know where it's putting stuff, and this is a non-PIE so absolute addresses are known to the linker.

Comment: Oops, I got that wrong; the `Hello` string *is* at `0x1000`, so apparently `-Ttext 0` did influence the position.  The .bin file is 129 MiB, but the non-zero bytes starting at 0x08048000 are the `...GNU...` note stuff.  `hexdump -C string.bin` shows it very clearly since it collapses runs of zeros.